# Error with insertion in postgres Database with my ASP.NET CORE API

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, auto-increment

I'm creating an ASP.NET CORE API and I have a problem when I want to insert data in my postgres database.

The insert data's doesn't auto increment themself and it always start with id = 0 even if i insert an other status

My controller is :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StatusController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly intranetApplicationAPIContext _context;

    public StatusController(intranetApplicationAPIContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Status>> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Status.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetStatus")]
    public ActionResult<Status> GetById(long id)
    {
        var status = _context.Status.Find(id);
        if (status == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return status;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Status status)
    {
        _context.Status.Add(status);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetStatus", new { id = status.Id }, status);
    }
```

Maybe the problem comes from .AsNoTracking() but I can't delete it because i will have this error :

> The instance of entity type 'Status' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

In my database, I see that I can do a sequence in order to auto increment but when I have to do my insert with this :

```
INSERT INTO status(state) VALUES ('test') RETURNING *;
```

How can I "translate" it in my statusController ?

Comment: What makes you think it *should* be magically done behind your back? Does the database driver provide something? Or maybe your table description?

Comment: If you want to see my model it look like this :


    public class Status
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

So in my postgres database I create a table status with id and state.
After that i put a constraint on id. (I work on pgadmin LTS by bigSQL)

Comment: So what makes you think it *should* auto-increment?

Comment: It should do it thinks to bigint in database

Comment: Does it do it if you insert a record by hand? I don't see why a bigint would auto-increment. Aren't the types that auto-increment called `serial`?

Comment: If I do a INSERT INTO status VALUES ('created') I have an error message cause postgresql want me to give a number for id column.

In my pgAdmin datatype i don't have serial or bigserial.

Comment: You need to pick a datatype that auto-increments then if you want that.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I have not used pgAdmin.

Comment: I find something in pgAdmin at least when I want to insert I have to do this :

INSERT INTO status(state) VALUES ('test') RETURNING *;

But how i can do this on my StatusController ?